# Generate a fixed length, deterministic identifiers from strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

I need to generate fixed length, no collisions identifiers based on varying in length input strings (hundreds of unique inputs). The ids need to be deterministic as identified objects will be accessed later knowing only the input strings.

I could use simply MD5, SHA-1 hashing but was wondering if there is a simple or better way to solve this?

Comment: You could just put them in a list and refer to them by their index.

Comment: And... what's exactly wrong with well known hash functions like md5  or sha1? It think this are one of the simplest ways to solve that.

Comment: As you tagged your question with Python, the hashlib module contains what you need.

Comment: Anyway... you can also use python builting [`hash`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) method to generate intergers from any hashable python object including string.  Integers have not "fixed length" but if you really need you can convert them "back" to fixed-length strings .

Comment: @mrCarnivore That would be hard as the input strings are not persistently stored in the system

Comment: @running.t Hashing was my first guess. Later I though if it's the go-to solution for this particular problem. Are MD5 and SHA-1 internals stable enough so the hashes won't change in a couple of months/years? Maybe a custom hashing function would be better?

Comment: @lolnoob MD5 is stable **always** It platform independant and so on. That is why you can use them for example to check integrity of files downloaded from internet. Internal python hash might not be stable, e.g. result my depend on architecture, python version etc. So I would definitely suggest md5 or similar in your case.

Comment: @running.t That was helpful. Thanks a lot. I'll go for MD5 then.

Comment: Also take a look at md5 article in wikipedia, especially at [algorithm section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Algorithm). This algorithm guarantees that from same input you will always get exactly the same output.

Comment: @lolnoob: That is an important information that you should have put in the question...